# Paste Clipboard Images Into Gmail Messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gmail, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the paste image from clipboard functionality work in Gmail and Google Chrome 12+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-ch)

How does it work in Chrome?
http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/pasting-images-into-messages-just-got.html

I tried build own function:
http://jsfiddle.net/bordeux/b8eW5/7/

but i don't know, how i can get clipboard data.  some ideas?

Comment: google has developers working for hours on end. i dont think your going to get the solution on a 7th revision fiddle

Comment: Seems like this question has already been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814

Comment: @Neal, you mean to tell me that finding the answers to longtail, highly domain-specific programming questions is *outside* the scope of Stack Overflow? I believe you are either confused or woefully ignorant.