# How to create a api in HTML 5 that is cut/copy/paste

Tags: file, html, extjs, uploader

I was planning to create a new web app based on extjs, but i need to create a file upload area where i can work on file uploading , i have tried drag and drop method in html 5 but we don't need that, we need a method where a user can copy a file whatever it is(not big than 20 mb)and that file location got copied on the clipboard and when we paste the file in the selected area of the uploader and the file gets uploaded, what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general access to the clipboard from browsers these days.  There is a flash object called zeroclipboard that can be used for some clipboard access.

For your particular need (if all the data is exchanged within your page), you may not need to use the actual clipboard and perhaps you can just use some global storage to store things that are copied for later paste (using your own copy/paste instead of clipboard operations).

Answer (score 1):

This Specification to achieve this is: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/
But seens that it isn't implemented in any browser yet (perhaps IE9)

This could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338207/230526

If not interested in standard based solution, firefox, because of the plugins API, have a workaround for this, that you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard

I also found this piece of code that promises to work on Webkit based browsers: http://forum.maxthon.com/viewthread.php?tid=79469&page=1#pid493997

If you need to have all browsers support, then Zero Clipboard as stated here, is the way to go.

UPDATE: Found this Jquery based script ( http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard ), that uses IE native API to access clipboard and Flash to all others. This could be a start point to merge all the others solutions and fallback to flash whether not available.

For Zero Clipboard, there is this one: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/