# JavaScript: How does pasting images into Gmail work?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gmail

In Gmail, I just noticed that you can paste (CTRL+P) an image directly into the body of the email message.

Question: how does this work? Does JavaScript allow this functionality, I thought not. Also, I don't believe any Java Applets or Flash is being loaded to allow this functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the paste image from clipboard functionality work in Gmail and Google Chrome 12+?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems my initial intuition about this was wrong, but this has actually been answered here: [How does the paste image from clipboard functionality work in Gmail and Google Chrome 12+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c)

For online images, google actually uses a reference to the original images http location. For images pasted locally, google uploads the image onto its own (cache) server and then sends the [img src '' /] pointing to that.

Yikes! Scary stuff, eh? Better not leave any confidential information in your clipboard (image, passwords, etc). and then unmindfully paste into a website that may be sniffing