# Get Clipboard Image Data in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, clipboard-pictures

I read many article about this. But i don't solve it. I want to get clipboard image data with javascript(in Firefox). When i use contenteditable div and press printScreen button and paste  with ctrl+v.this is work properly but how do you get this image data with javascript or any other plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to make it work like gmail?

if yes then i guess **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c)** can help you.

**Edit:**

alright, then [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253468/get-pasted-image-from-clipboard-firefox) can help.

Comment: I have read this solution but i want to run that code firefox.