# Elegant and reliable way to cancel paste event but dispatch it later

Tags: javascript, events

Pasting of images currently *quite sucks* in javascript API. [There's a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15304663/607407) in which you make the user paste the image in contenteditable div. The browser then creates a `<img>` element which you can retrieve using `.getElementsByTagName` method.

But if user pastes files copied from Explorer or similar program, these don't appear in div but can be retrieved using API.

```
<div id='paste' contenteditable='true'>Paste</div>
```

So I have one `onpaste` event which is fully capable of retrieving pasted file (of any file type):

```
paste.addEventListener('paste', function(event){
  var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData);

  /**Try to get a file**/
  var files = items.items || items.files;

  if(files.length>0) {
    //Read the file
    applyFile(files[0].getAsFile? files[0].getAsFile():files[0]);
    //Do not input any text
    event.preventDefault();
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
  }
  //No files = try to paste text in HTML div
});
```

In fact, the paste event origin is a `<input>`, so to get the text pasted as HTML, I steal focus from input field before paste event:

```
//When pasting, focus on the PASTE element
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==86&&e.ctrlKey) {
    paste.focus();
    console.log("Focusing the div");
  }
});
```

Now after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, if there's no file other event called [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) will eventually dispatch on the div:

```
paste.addEventListener('input', function(event){
  //An array of pasted images
  var images = this.getElementsByTagName("img");
  if(images.length!=0) {
     //Do something
     ...
  }
  //Clear the div (image references will be lost!)
  this.innerHTML = "";
  //Focus back on the input
  input.focus();

});
```

As you can see if an image is pasted in the textarea it will be processed. But if not, the paste event will not do anything!

How can I eventually let the paste event happen in the textarea if no images were pasted?

I tried to save the event in variable:

```
var lastPaste;
paste.addEventListener('paste', function(event){
  lastPast = event;
  ...
}
```

And then dispatch it:

```
paste.addEventListener('input', function(event){
   ...
     //Focus back on the input
   input.focus();
   //The paste event now must be dispatched in textarea:
   input.dispatchEvent(lastPaste);
   lastPaste = null;
}
```

It doesn't do anything. Nothing is pasted.

Comment: text should go to _#paste_, just like the images, so use paste.textContent.trim() to get approx the same text that would otherwise drop into the input

Comment: I'm not satisfied with *approx*. Also there may be other listeners on checkbox that handle the pasted text. And most inportantly, I want to avoid re-inventing the paste on caret position.

Comment: change _files_ to var files = items.files, and after your file _if_, add another if to handle text: var cd= event.clipboardData, n=n=cd.types.indexOf('text/html'); if(n!=1){        cd.items[n].getAsString(alert.bind(window)); };

Comment: There's `var` statement and it always was there. Also I don't understand how the rest solves the text insert problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the text content in your "paste" input and save it in case there's no images.

`.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`

Also note that `.clipboardData.files` is not the same thing as `.clipboardData.items` and naming `.clipboardData` `items` is just confusing as they're different structures.