# How can I paste an image from the clipboard onto a Canvas element using Dart?

Tags: html, image, dart, clipboard, paste

I'm using Dart to develop a personal whiteboard Chrome app and it is sometimes useful to be able to quickly copy and paste an image (e.g. a slide from a presentation, a diagram or a handout) so that I can add notes over the image while teaching a class or giving a presentation.

How can I paste an image stored on the clipboard onto a canvas element in Dart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, [this answer to the same question for JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338207/1340742) is almost directly applicable. A Dart translation might look something like:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var can = new CanvasElement()
    ..width = 600
    ..height = 600
  ;

  var con = can.getContext('2d');

  document.onPaste.listen((e) {
    var blob = e.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onLoad.listen((e) {
      var img = new ImageElement()
        ..src = (e.target as FileReader).result;
      img.onLoad.listen((_) {
        con.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      });
    });
    reader.readAsDataUrl(blob);
  });

  document.body.children.add(can);
}
```

Comment: In the latest build of Dart (0.7.3_r27487), this code doesn't work... It seems that the item(_) method has been removed from the DataTransferItemList class...

Comment: I can't manage to generate the Paste event. I tried putting a breakpoint but it doesn't stop, so I suppose I'm missing something.

Comment: Update: as of Dart 1.1.1, the DataTransferItemList class is more analogous to other lists - instead of using e.clipboardData.items.item(index) we can simply use e.clipBoardData.items[index] (which makes more sense); the above code edited to reflect this change and currently working.

Comment: I had to get the item 1. With 0 I don't get any event (Load,LoadStart,etc..). I tried the paste event on the Document though.

Comment: Good point. Otherwise we have to make sure that the canvas has the focus; I've made the edit. Index zero is working for me... that's odd.

Comment: I tested it on Chrome (under Linux). That might be the reason?