# Paste inside a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dart

There is already a [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916968/how-can-i-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard-onto-a-canvas-element-using-dart) about it, but it's obsolete.
I haven't found any help from dartlang's site or googling around, so here is again the problem.

```
document.onPaste.listen((e)  {
  //var items = e.clipboardData.getData("image"); 
  var blob = e.clipboardData.items.item(0).getAsFile();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onLoad.listen((e) {
    var img = new ImageElement()
    ..src = (e.target as FileReader).result;
    img.onLoad.listen((_) {
      mainContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    });
  });
  reader.readAsDataUrl(blob);
});
```

The "items" was a previous test, while "blob" shouldn't work, because google removed item(). I haven't found any other way to do that. Last possible solution is to look for a javascript library to do that. Note that I'm using the onPaste even on the whole document because on the canvas it wasn't working, at least for me.

Comment: If you need this to get an image file into the canvas you could use the onDrop event and drag&drop those files. But if have the same use case as the linked question that's not what you want to do, or do you?

Comment: Use case is a bit similar. People need to be able to see images possibly even from other hosts and apply filters to them. Drag and Drop is cumbersome. Copy an url might be a solution or as last resort is to download a file and upload to my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I paste an image from the clipboard onto a Canvas element using Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916968/how-can-i-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard-onto-a-canvas-element-using-dart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916968/how-can-i-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard-onto-a-canvas-element-using-dart) I mentioned before is not obsolete anymore. I'm answering my own question to make it more readable than just an edit.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
  @DomName('DataTransferItemList.__getter__')
  @DocsEditable()
  @Experimental() // untriaged
  DataTransferItem __getter__(int index) native "DataTransferItemList___getter___Callback";
```

the only available method to access the Data is private and marked as experimental.

You can star the bugs

- [DataTransferItemList is only supported on Webkit](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4622)
- [HTML Docs: Add sample code for the Data Transfer API.](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8260)

I was not able to aquire image data only a path or an url but you can try:

```dart
var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text');
```

When you examine the ClipboardData.types property you may get a format parameter that fits better to your needs.

Comment: I will have a look again to getData, but my first experiment with "image" wasn't successfull..