# How does Github takes screenshots from the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, github

On Github it is possible in the comment textarea to copy paste a screenshot on at least OSX.

How does they do that with javascript?

How is the image received? Base64?

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c

Comment: @ikaros45 Yes, exactly. Tried the solution out in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinsimper/NR3bh/