# HTML5 and JavaScript: How do I make paste handling fully/more asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, clipboarddata

I'm implementing copy-paste functionality into a browser application using the ClipboardData API, [as explained in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338207/1214731)

The `FileReader::readAsDataURL(blob)` provides asynchronous reading of the file data, which is great.

```
var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
   /*add item (i.e. image) to page*/}; //callback

var blob = items[0].getAsFile(); //not async
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); //async
```

Questions:
1) Is there a way to make the `DataTransferItem::getAsFile()` method asynchronous?
2) Is there a way to get `FileReader` to take a `DataTransferItem` as an argument so it can do the `async` itself like it does already with blobs?
3) Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the DataTransferItem::getAsFile() method asynchronous?

No. [It's specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/editing.html#dom-datatransferitem-getasfile) as synchronous. However, there is absolutely no reason to make this asynchronous - a reference to the File is quickly constructed and does not incorporate any data shoveling. Just as `input.files` does synchronously get you references to not-yet-read-in files.

> Is there a way to get `FileReader` to take a `DataTransferItem` as an argument so it can do the async itself like it does already with blobs?

No. It just takes the `item.getAsFile()` blob, and can read that in asynchronously.