# Is there a single cross-browser solution for uploading images from the clipboard in JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, applet

**Note:** *I need a solution that uploads images from the **System Clipboard** specifically, as opposed to uploading **files** via drag and drop.*

What I am looking for is essentially exactly how Google do it in GMail:

1. Select an image in Word or Paint (for example) and copy it to the clipboard.
2. Switch to GMail and press CTRL+V in a new mail.
3. A little "busy icon" appears at the cursor while the image is taken from the clipboard and uploaded to the server.
4. The image is then displayed in the mail as a standard `img` element.

I know this is already possible in [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c), but I need a cross-browser solution and even GMail doesn't support this functionality in IE11 at time of writing this (April 2014).

I've noticed that JIRA (Atlassian) uses a Java Applet for its "Attach Screenshot" functionality but I would rather avoid using an Applet if possible, unless it really is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the system clipboard while being cross-browser seems to be a real nightmare and something never done to this day. For java applet you can check Liveconnect but its far from being perfect.