# Pasting from a file browser and HTML5 Clipboard API

Tags: javascript, html, clipboarddata

I'm trying to add an image paste function to my web application, using the standard routine:

```
$('textarea').on('paste', function (ev) {
    var clipboardData = ev.originalEvent.clipboardData;

    $.each(clipboardData.items, function (i, item) {
        if (item.type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(item.getAsFile());
            reader.addEventListener('loadend', ...);
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

The full sample can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/t8t2zj6k/

It works correctly when I copy & paste an image from an image viewer software, but when I'm trying to do the same thing using a file browser (e.g. Finder on Mac or Nautilus on Linux) as a result I get only a text string with the file path or even an image with file type icon instead of an original file.

Is there any way to handle pastes from a file browser properly?

Comment: Possibly this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c

Comment: @lemieuxster, thanks, but unfortunately I'm already using the exact same solution provided in the accepted answer. My case is a bit different - while the basic paste function is working well, there's an issue with pasting from Finder.

Comment: Seems to maybe be an issue with Chrome? I don't see anything in Safari or Firefox. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361980

Comment: @lemieuxster, thank you! The bug report totally explains this weird behavior. Perhaps you should add it as an answer to the question so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to maybe be an issue with Chrome? I don't see anything in Safari or Firefox. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361980

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would like to paste image as `data:`

Go look at [HTML5 paste image to page](https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/IoJbg)