# Upload images from Clipboard

Tags: vaadin, clipboard

I am working with Vaadin and I want to upload an image from client's clipboard to the server.

I tried:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

try {
    BufferedImage image = 
            (BufferedImage)clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);                     
}    
catch(UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
    ufe.printStackTrace();
}        
catch(IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, this code only works in the local machine.

How can I allow users to upload their clipboard's image?

Comment: I think this is not possible so far, cause Vaadin doesn't support it right now. You can write your own addon which handles this over JavaScript etc.

Comment: I'm not even sure any web browser allows you to access the clipboard

Comment: I also remember something similar to what @AndréSchild is saying due to security issue. Nonetheless, things may have changed since I last looked, and as per MarcelHöll's suggestion, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c) seems to suggest otherwise and may give you a starting point

Answer (score 2):

You can't get clients clipboard content (even using JavaScript) due to security concerns. There is however way to handle [onpaste event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp) on a client side and pass the data to the server side. This requires writing some code in JavaScript (you can always browse through Vaadin addons - maybe someone already has done that and shared with others).