# How can I get data from clipboard in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, paste

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
    clipboard = e.clipboardData.getData();
    console.log(clipboard);
});
```

This is my test code. I want to get clipboardData, but it comes out "42 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getData' on 'DataTransfer': 1 argument required, but only 0 present." when I try to paste a picture.

When I just paste, I can see

`DataTransfer {dropEffect: "none", effectAllowed: "uninitialized", items:DataTransferItemList, types: Array[1], files: FileList}`

There is some data.

But if I try to open, it shows

```
dropEffect:"none"
effectAllowed:"uninitialized"
files:FileList
items:DataTransferItemList
types:Array[0]
__proto__:DataTransfer
```

There is no data.

Comment: You have to specify the type of data you are looking for. It is accessible under `evt.clipBoardData.types` so you probably can just do `var clipboard = evt.clipboardData.getData(evt.clipboardData.types[0])`. For a more complete solution see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6804718/3702797) to a dupe.

Comment: That helps a lot！ Thanks! But if I want to get the files, what should I do?

Comment: I have tried evt.clipboardData.files. But when I paste, it comes out "FileList {length: 0}".

Comment: For reading files, you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c) post