# Pasting an image onto an HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html form that will post the message to a message board:[image]

But it wont allow me to paste an image in the text box that displays the message. Is this a possibility? So  basically I was to display it a similar way that I have in this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste image from clipboard to web form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251528/paste-image-from-clipboard-to-web-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload picture to server from clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167022/upload-picture-to-server-from-clipboard)

Comment: Some JavaScript lib solution but the pasting functionality works only in chrome for now, but drag and drop works for all modern browsers. https://github.com/Rovak/InlineAttachment

Answer (score -1):

1. Put your picture on imgur.com and paste it in a forum post inside of

```
[img]put the link here[/img]
```

2. Or try and specify that the server accepts only image files in the file upload, read more here:
   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Since it is not entirely clear what the OP is asking it is hard to say if this is really answering the question. You can add a comment to the question and get clarification. The OP seems to be asking if it is possible to paste an image not just a link to an image into a text box.