# Clipboard image to file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have been looking for a solution to this problem, but i could not find it. Is it possible to have HTML button that will convert my Clipboard into a file using javascript. In other words i need a button that will convert my CTRL + C into a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party library like [Joel Besada Pasteboard](https://github.com/JoelBesada/pasteboard) or you can use the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338207/3242048).