# Paste an image and send binary

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I need to paste an image and it will upload to my server. [I've seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338207/14511890) and it works great, my only issue is that is returns a base64 image. Is there any way I can alter this code to return image binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Given that `item.getAsFile();` already gives you a `File` object, so you can upload that directly with `XMLHttpRequest.send`:

```
document.addEventListener( 'paste', onPaste );

function onPaste( ev ) {
    const items = ( ev.clipboardData || ev.originalEvent.clipboardData ).items;
    for( const item of items ) {
        if( item.kind === 'file' ) {
            const file = item.getAsFile();
            uploadFileUsingXhr( file );
        }
    }
}

function uploadFileUsingXhr( file ) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'POST', '/your-upload-handler', /*async:*/ true );
    xhr.send( file );
    // TODO: xhr.upload.progress reporting
}
```